# Weird getter name in the automatic generation of them by eclipse-cdt

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In the specific case than the variable name starts by 1 character the automatic getter generated by eclipse remove this character, for example:

```
private:

int xVel;
int yVel;
int zVel;
```

generates:

```
public:

int getVel();  //<-- this return xVel;
int getVel();  //<-- this return yVel;
int getVel();  //<-- this return zVel;
```

and it is so annoying for me because creates 3 functions with the same name.

I google it and I didn't find a clear answer because the name convention, if I'm not wrong, says that the first letter is converted to lower case but no mention anything about remove characters. I mean, in camelCase convention the getter for variable xVel is getXVel() or at least I expect that.

The options that I can edit by preferences don't solve my problem:

[image]

Is it a bug? Is there some solution?

The versions used of eclipse-cdt are:

*Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800*

and

*Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200*

Both with the same behavior

Comment: Why are you using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ when developing Java?
Works as expected on my machine. Windows 10 Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Build id: 20190614-1200.

Comment: I'm developing C++, why do you think I'm developing java?

Comment: Because you are refering Java coding conventions. Please change it and remove the Java tag again. The link does not work anyway.

Comment: I guess eclipse-cdt follows the same conventions as eclipse java. I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. I would encourage you to file it in [CDT's bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT).